WinDbg: committed unknown memory is much bigger than the eeheap output
This question is based on my another post: .NET service high memory usage analysis with WinDbg. But I summarized the issue and focus on the most critical part.
Simply speaking, I have a service reports 1.4GB memory usage, which is higher than expectation. I analyze the memory usage based on the dump file.
0:000> !address -summary

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                338     7ffe`d06bb000 ( 127.995 TB)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                            2503        0`cdc3c000 (   3.215 GB)  67.78%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                             4356        0`61cf9000 (   1.528 GB)  32.22%    0.00%


The important data here is the 1.528 GB committed memory. This value keeps same as the size of dump file. I think it makes sense to me.
Next, I run the more advanced command with filter like this
!address -f:MEM_COMMIT -c:".echo %1 %3 %5 %7"

This command will output all the committed memory region, and for each region prints its base address(%1), region size(%3), state(%5) and type(%7). The output goes as follows:
0x5f3a0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f3a1000 0x2ab000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f64c000 0xb000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f657000 0x1b000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f672000 0x2000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f674000 0x2d000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x7ffe0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Other
0x4580ca7000 0x5000 MEM_COMMIT Stack
...thousands of lines omitted...

Basically, I can get the distribution of the committed memory for various types. Ok? And then I write a script to handle the output line by line, the target is to know what is the memory size for each type in the 1.528GB committed memory. Then the result is
Memory by Type:
type: Image 233.52344MB
type: Other 1.8007812MB
type: Stack 3.796875MB
type: TEB 0.71875MB
type: PEB 0.00390625MB
type: Heap 84.88281MB
type: <unknown> 1240.2461MB

The most important thing to me is that the unknown part is 1240MB. right?
Next, I want to double check it with command eeheap which returns all the managed heap in CLR runtime, right? The output contains GC heap and loader heap and a few small heap, totally add up to roughly 140MB.
Then the question is why the committed unknown memory is much bigger than the eeheap output? Can anyone explain this?
